# Point and Polygon Data refusing to display: corrupt data?

Tags: qgis, polygon, layers, point, display

I have two sets of shapefiles, one point data and one polygon data. Both were sent as part of a bigger set of data.

Neither the point or polygon data will display when loaded into QGIS. The raw data has not been edited, the CRS is correct for the project and layer (27700). I have tried multiple times to load these layers with no success. I have have remaped the Spatial CRS from within the layer properties.

I am at my wits end trying to work out what is wrong!

Comment: Please **edit** to clarify:  How many features in each shapefile?  How large are the component files?  Does each file draw if they are the first (and only) layer in the canvas?  What is the contents of the .prj (and/or qpj) of each shapefile?  Have you changed the coordinate reference of  either data layer?

Comment: Try loading it in OGR.  See what errors OGR gives you, to help pinpoint the source of corruption.

Comment: Perhaps you could share your shapefiles on a public server so that others could test it?

Comment: Unfortunately the data I work with is not suitable for public distribution, sorry!